# connection failed while connecting to OpenOffice .org

Tags: java, openoffice.org

```
File file = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append(s1).toString());
        file.renameTo(new File((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append("$$tsjoof$$.xls").toString()));
      // SocketOpenOfficeConnection socketopenofficeconnection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection();
         OpenOfficeConnection socketopenofficeconnection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);

        try
        {
            String s3 = (new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append("$$tsjoof$$.xls").append(".ods").toString();
            DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry defaultdocumentformatregistry = new DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry();
            File file4 = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append("$$tsjoof$$.xls").toString());
            File file6 = new File(s3);
            socketopenofficeconnection.connect();
            if(socketopenofficeconnection.isConnected())
            {
                OpenOfficeDocumentConverter openofficedocumentconverter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(socketopenofficeconnection);
                openofficedocumentconverter.convert(file4, defaultdocumentformatregistry.getFormatByFileExtension("xls"), file6, defaultdocumentformatregistry.getFormatByFileExtension("ods"));
            } else
            {
                File file7 = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append("$$tsjoof$$.xls").toString());
                file7.renameTo(new File((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append(s1).toString()));
                throw new OpenOfficeConnectException("Unable to connect to OpenOffice.org to convert Excel Document.");
            }
        }
```

It is giving an exception as

```
connection failed: socket,host=localhost,port=1234,tcpNoDelay=1: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.disconnect(AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.java:88)
    at fileToXliff.ExcelImporter.convert(ExcelImporter.java:90)
    at fileToXliff.MainGui.jbtnConvertActionPerformed(MainGui.java:667)
    at fileToXliff.MainGui.access$800(MainGui.java:55)
    at fileToXliff.MainGui$9.actionPerformed(MainGui.java:179)
```

What should I need to do .

Answer (score 1):

You should check on which address is listening OpenOffice and use that address. because it might not listening on `localhost (127.0.0.1)`.

```
SocketOpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection("192.168.0.1", 8100);
```

Comment: still same problem it giving

Comment: I don't know which part of your code is connection to `localhost:1234`. Check your code may be you manually entered the port parameter 1234.

Comment: It is OpenOfficeConnection socketopenofficeconnection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(1234);

Comment: yes but i have added your code SocketOpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection("192.168.0.1", 8100); but still it s giving an exception as 
connection failed: socket,host=192.168.0.1,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: the address is not for your concrete machine, you should check the interface on which your openoffice run and substitute that address.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40065/discussion-between-aditya-and-nikpon)

Answer (score 0):

The connection was refused. Without reading the documentation, I'm guessing OpenOffice is not listening on port 1234?

Comment: Any solution for that?

Comment: What does the documentation say you should do in order to use this API? Are you following what the documentation says you should do?