# OpenOffice convert doc to pdf with JAVA

Tags: java, converters, openoffice.org

I know its have multiple question about it. But I've already read tons of it and it still doesnt work.
I have installed OpenOffice to my comp :
https://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html

I have also tried this solution, doesnt work :
[connection failed while connecting to OpenOffice .org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616742/connection-failed-while-connecting-to-openoffice-org)

If I want to run my code i get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: connection failed: socket,host=localhost,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.connect(AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.java:79)
        at TestCon.main(TestCon.java:24

)
```

**How can I mange to Connect to my openoffice program.**
PS: I want to use it on windows 7 64x

I use this simple code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.ConnectException;

import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.DocumentConverter;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.SocketOpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;


public class TestCon {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ConnectException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConnectException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File inputFile = new File("Resume.doc");
        File outputFile = new File("document.pdf");

        // connect to an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100
        OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
        connection.connect();

        // convert
        DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
        converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

        // close the connection
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have "an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100" ? Try to follow the documentation at http://www.artofsolving.com/node/10.

Comment: Also, question title should reflect on the problem you're having - you can't connect to OpenOffice service, whether the code you use for converting into pdf is correct or not is not exactly relevant. It looks fine by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to start the openoffice service:

```
 soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard
```

Then you can connect to this service and convert you document.